# Storing non-repetitive combinations of table's rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, combinations

The table **goals** has 8 items, i'd like to store the non repetitive combination of these goals.

```html
ID|name
--------
1|goal-1
2|goal-2
3|goal-3
4|goal-4
5|goal-5
6|goal-6
7|goal-7
8|goal-8
```

I used this formula to calculate/generate all the necessary combinations:
**[C(n,k) = n!/k!( n − k)!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)**

- n = 8, k = 3 => c(8,3) = 56 combinations
- n = 8, k = 2 => c(8,2) = 28 combinations
- n = 8, k = 1 => c(8,1) =  8 combinations

Totally i have 92 combinations

Actually on frontend this is a checkbox list, where the user can selects 1 - 2 or max 3 goals. Based on the user's selections the system should recommends a product.

Basically i want something like this:

- user selected the **cat-1, cat-3, cat-4 (ids:1,3,4)** => recommend the **product-1**
- user selected the **cat-3, cat-4 (ids:3,4)** => recommend the **product-2**
- .....
- user selected the **cat-1 (ids:1)** => recommend the **product-2**

I don't know how to store the goal_combination_ids and set the relations between these tables. (I want to keep open the possibility to change the recommended_product for a specific goal's combination anytime.)

[image]

Comment: You switched from goals to categories.  What you want is a truth table.  Your Suggestion table would have three goal columns and a product column.  Each goal column can either be a goal number or NULL.  You'd need an application to help you manage the Suggestion table.  The "trick" after any changes would be to sort the Suggestion rows so that the three goal rows come first, then the two goal rows, and finally, the one goal rows.  You would need to read this entire table into memory before using it.  Basically, you start from the top and keep checking until you find a goal match.

Comment: How confident are you that n will remain 8, and k will remain 3? 
As @GilbertLeBlanc writes, what you want is a truth table. The challenge is looking up the combination of criteria in your truth table. If you can encode the goals in an 8-bit integer, you'll get _very_ fast lookup, but changing n might be tricky.